# Uploading images on aws s3

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mern

I am developing a mern stack app. Now I want o upload my images on aws S3, So I need guide that if a user uploads the image on s3 then how I can get image back for that particular user.
If a user uploads a profile picture then how I can retrieve the image for that user because I am storing them on the s3 not on mongodb. I need guide for thing.

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
    accessKeyId: "",
    secretAccessKey: "",
    region: "",
  });

const upload = (bucketName, id) =>
    multer({
      storage: multerS3({
        s3,
        bucket: bucketName,
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
        },
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
          console.log(id)
          cb(null, `image-${id}.jpeg`);
          ID=''
        },
      }),
    });

 exports.setProfilePic =('/updateuser/updateimg/:id', (req,res)=>{
   
    const uploadSingle = upload("medic18577", req.params.id).single(
      "img"
    );
    uploadSingle(req, res, async (err) => {
      if (err)
       { return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message })};
       try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.id)
        if(user){
          ID=user.id
          console.log(ID)
          user.img = req.file.location
          
          //res.status(200).json({ data: req.file.location, msg:'img uploaded' });
          await user.save()
          res.json(user.img)
        }else {
         return res.json('User not Found')
        }
       } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
        res.status(500).send('Server Error')
       }
  
     
    });
  })
```

Comment: How are the users uploading the image? Are they doing it via a web page in your app? The app should be [Uploading objects using presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) so that it controls _who_ can upload and what the uploaded file will be called.

Comment: when the user uploads the pic first time. The useeffect in the user component calls the loaduser function but when the user updatesthe pic 2nd time the useeffect does call the loaduser. the img save as follows on the image.UserId.jpeg. Now What I have to do to remove that thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the filename/key of uploaded image/s in your mongoDB, that way when you want to display it, you append your AWS url with the filename/key.

```
{
   "user": "John",
   "image": "1235.jpg"
}
```

while displaying:

```
<img src=`${awsUrl}/${user.image}` />
```

Comment: I have sent it using file object and getting the url. Now the problem is that every time it sends a new pic for the particular user ,new image not replacing the old image